# SQlite funcão MAX - Pegar o valor mais alto

Tags: android, sqlite

Tenho no `Sqlite` um campo chamado `date_start`, que guarda a data de uma caminhada.

Este, é do tipo `Long` e guarda a data em `milisegundos`.

Gostaria, através de uma consulta, retornar o valor mais alto (a última caminhada registrada).

Para isso tentei o seguinte:

```
Cursor cursor = dataBase.query(table, properties, "MAX(date_start)", null,null, null, null, null);
```

Mas ocorre o seguinte erro:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: misuse of aggregate function
>   MAX() (code 1)

Como faço para pegar o valor mais alto deste campo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o o metodo rawQuery() que retornar um Cursor, e nesse caso que so tem um campo pegue o index 0;

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select MAX(date_start) from Nometabela", null);
cursor.cursor.getString(0);
```

Na minha aplicação estou usando o count()

Comment: No meu caso, por se tratar de um long uso: **cursor.getLong(0)**